# Multi-tenant authentication, IMustHaveTenant entity in ASP.NET Boilerplate Module Zero

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, multi-tenant, asp.net-core-2.0, aspnetboilerplate

## Multi-Tenant Authentication

I have created a new tenant from the swagger UI as an admin and I can check in the data *the tenant created successfully together with admin account*.

**Now how do I login as the admin of the newly created tenant?**

Cos I tried Token-authenticating via Postman, specifying `tenancyName` in the request body and it only seems to authenticate the admin from `default` tenant - *even when I put in rubbish in the* `tenancyName` field, it won't detect any error or exception.

I check the configuration value in the `CoreModule.cs` and **`MultiTenancyEnabled` has been set to `true`**

[image]

## Entity Relation with Tenant

Also I would like to relate one of my entity with the `tenant` entity. So I based the class on `IMustHaveTenant` interface along side `FullAuditedEntity` like this:

```
public class Rule: FullAuditedEntity, IMustHaveTenant
{
    public string columnA { get; set; }
    public string columnB { get; set; }
    public string columnC { get; set; }
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
}
```

Is it enough or do I have to further put in any codes in the `DbContext`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now how do I login as the admin of the newly created tenant?

For [Token Based Authentication](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/Startup-Template-Angular#authentication), send the tenant id in the **Abp.TenantId** header.

In Postman, click on **Headers**, add the Key as `Abp.TenantId` and the Value as your tenant id. If you just created a new tenant, that would be `2` as there is a Default tenant with id 1.

> Also I would like to relate one of my entity with the `tenant` entity. [...] Is it enough or do I have to further put in any codes in the `DbContext`?

You have to add a `DbSet` in your [`DbContext`](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Entity-Framework-Core?searchKey=dbset#dbcontext):

```cs
public class MyDbContext : AbpDbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```