# How to assign TenantId to abpsession in login process API?

Tags: .net, session, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

Application(aspnetboilerplate) is a standalone API service. For login used **TokenAuthController/Authenticate** as post request, it's logging but cannot be getting the Tenant details there. As the **AbpSession.TenantId** is not set. Below is the code. Actually, I am getting null value for AbpSession when trying to fetch the records for a user with tenant login. But without a tenant, it's working fine.

```
   [AbpAllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<AuthenticateResultModel> Authenticate([FromBody] AuthenticateModel model)
    {
        var loginResult = await GetLoginResultAsync(
            model.UserNameOrEmailAddress,
            model.Password,
            GetTenancyNameOrNull()
        );

        var accessToken = CreateAccessToken(CreateJwtClaims(loginResult.Identity));
        await _sessionAppService.GetCurrentLoginInformations();



        return new AuthenticateResultModel
        {
            AccessToken = accessToken,
            EncryptedAccessToken = GetEncrpyedAccessToken(accessToken),
            ExpireInSeconds = (int)_configuration.Expiration.TotalSeconds,
            UserId = loginResult.User.Id
        };
    }
```

Comment: Did you send Abp.TenantId in the request header? See https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Multi-Tenancy#determining-current-tenant

Comment: you need to send the `Abp.TenantId` header

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi-tenant authentication, IMustHaveTenant entity in ASP.NET Boilerplate Module Zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47670680/multi-tenant-authentication-imusthavetenant-entity-in-asp-net-boilerplate-modul)

Comment: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Abp-Session
here is your answer... You can use session.Use(tenantId, userId) to session

Answer (score 2):

I just ran in to the same issues and the way you solve this is by adding the tenant Id to the header prior to calling Authenticate

**Here is my working version**

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Abp.TenantId", "3234");
```

Call you Authenticate method ensuring the httpClient above is used.

For example
new TokenAuthServiceProxyClient(httpClient).AuthenticateAsync(body: body);